# Can not get json response using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently developing a Ruby on rails 3 application.

My server controller function render a json object as response:

```
class DaysController < BaseController
   ...
   def the_days
     ...
     render :json => days
   end
end
```

In my javascript,I use the following code to get json response from server( that's from `the_day` function in controller)

```
$.getJSON(  
             url,  
             {emp_id: emp_id},
             function(data) {
                     var result = data.response;
                     alert(result) 
                     alert(data)
                 },
                 "json"
        );
```

I use **firefox** browswer and checked with **Firebug**, in Firebug Net->XHR, I see the Get request is successful, and the response "days" is there. That's both request and response are successful.

But I did not see the two alert window defined in the above `$.getJSON` function, why? Why I can not get the response "**days**" in `$.getJSON` function??

**-----------------Edited------------------**

I edited my code to this one:

```
$.ajax({
            url: myURL,

            type: 'GET',

            data: {
                emp_id: emp_id
            },

            dataType: "json",

            success: function(data) {
                alert("hi");
                alert(data)
            }
        });
```

When I run this code, the browser is stuck at `success: function(data)`

Answer (score 2):

If `data` is coming back `null`, but the response was otherwise successful, I'd say that you're sending the request in a manner that violates the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The request needs to be sent to the same host/port/protocol that served the original page.

If this is only an issue in your development environment, you can test in `Chrome` by launching it from a Terminal application with `--disable-web-security`.

---

**EDIT:** Try changing the parameter name from `data` to something else, like `dat` or whatever.

Then try an alert:

```
alert( dat );
```

I've heard of some browsers having trouble with the `data` parameter when you utilize the `data` property of an AJAX call.

Comment: @Mellon: Is that the *only* alert? Make the callback as simple as possible. Try `alert('test')`. If you can, please post more information.

Comment: Hi, even the alert('test') is not poping... by the way, 'days' is a string

Comment: @Mellon: I see your update. Did you try changing `data` to something else? Are there any errors in the console? Try changing the `dataType` to `text`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is that `data` does not have a response property.  Try alerting just the `data` variable.  It should be the `days` object itself.

Comment: +1 I think this is more likely it. I missed the *'and the response "days" is there'* part. At the same time, I'd think the alert would still occur in that case. Hard to say with the info provided.

Comment: "The response days is there" means in the Firebug tool in firefox browser, I see the response message is the "days" returned by the controller, that's the response is successful.

Comment: @Mellon - the documents suggest that getJSON only takes three parameters, with the second being optional.  What happens if you remove the type parameter `"json"`?

Comment: Hi tvansosson, I removed the "json" parameter, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could just leave a comment but I guess I don't have access to that yet.

Anyway, I'd start with something even more basic. Add some text alerts just to make sure you're actually making it to where you think you are. ie...

```
$.getJSON(  
             url,  
             {emp_id: emp_id},
             function(data) {
                     alert('hi')  // add this
                     var result = data.response;
                     alert('bye') // add maybe even this
                     alert(result) 
                     alert(data)
                 },
                 "json"
        );
```

Sometimes when I'm debugging I find that even my most basic assumptions are wrong.

**Edit:** here's some sample code from working code I recently implemented

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'users/check_username',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          username: username
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(user_exists) {
          alert(user_exists)      // CHANGE THIS PART
        }
      });
```

Comment: Hi, you are right, I tried your code, even the alert('hi') is not poping up...I am wondering why??

Comment: I'm editing my post to include working code I've used recently. Check it out for now. I have to head out but I'll check back later.

Comment: Based on your code in your editing post, I modified my code, and it get stuck at "success: function(user_exists)". See my edited post above.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the code again. This was a direct cut/paste from code I'm using cuz I was in a rush.

Comment: Just edit the `success: function(user_exists)` part, put an alert there.

Comment: Your code looks like you're missing a semicolon after the last alert

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not sending the correct header in your ruby application. Firebug should report the response `Content Type` as `application/json` because that is what jquery is expecting it to be.

You could try changing the `datatype` in your ajax call to html to see if your `alert`s work with that, but that doesn't really help with the json parsing.

Comment: In firebug response, it shows "Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*;"

Comment: If it says "accept" that's not the response header, that is the request header.

Answer (score 0):

ALL, finally, I figured out the root cause. The reason is simply because of "**Invalid json data**" returned in server. That's in rails controller function '`def the_days`':

```
render :json => days
```

should be modified to

```
render :json => days.to_json
```

Then, everything works smoothly:) Thank you all anyhow!